# Is mysql concurrent connection limit per mysql user or limit per localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new here but got log of benefit from this site.
I'm planning on large php/mysql website, but confusing about mysql concurrent connection limit.
Is that limit per mysql database or limit per localhost/cpanel account?
If it limit per mysql database. So in case I have a dedicated mysql database for each end-user, then for example 1000 databases per 1000 end-user, but I only have 1 mysql-user that grant access to that all 1000 databases. Can it be ok?
If it limit per mysql-user. Is pool connections can be a solution this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are system variables to control both.  As stated in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections):

> - [`max_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections)
>
>   ```
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   | Command-Line Format  | --max_connections=#   |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   | Option-File Format   | max_connections       |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   | Option Sets Variable | Yes, max_connections  |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   | Variable Name        | max_connections       |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   | Variable Scope       | Global                |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   | Dynamic Variable     | Yes                   |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   |                      | Permitted Values      |
>   +                      +---------+-------------+
>   |                      | Type    | numeric     |
>   +                      +---------+-------------+
>   |                      | Default | 151         |
>   +                      +---------+-------------+
>   |                      | Range   | 1 .. 100000 |
>   +----------------------+-----------------------+
>   ```
>
>   The maximum permitted number of simultaneous client connections. By default, this is 151. See [Section C.5.2.7, “`Too many connections`”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/too-many-connections.html), for more information.
>
>   Increasing this value increases the number of file descriptors that [*`mysqld`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqld.html) requires. See [Section 8.4.3.1, “How MySQL Opens and Closes Tables”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/table-cache.html), for comments on file descriptor limits.
> - [`max_user_connections`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections)
>
>   ```
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   | Command-Line Format  | --max_user_connections=#  |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   | Option-File Format   | max_user_connections      |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   | Option Sets Variable | Yes, max_user_connections |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   | Variable Name        | max_user_connections      |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   | Variable Scope       | Global, Session           |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   | Dynamic Variable     | Yes                       |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   |                      | Permitted Values          |
>   +                      +---------+-----------------+
>   |                      | Type    | numeric         |
>   +                      +---------+-----------------+
>   |                      | Default | 0               |
>   +                      +---------+-----------------+
>   |                      | Range   | 0 .. 4294967295 |
>   +----------------------+---------------------------+
>   ```
>
>   The maximum number of simultaneous connections permitted to any given MySQL user account. A value of 0 (the default) means “no limit.”
>
>   This variable has a global value that can be set at server startup or runtime. It also has a read-only session value that indicates the effective simultaneous-connection limit that applies to the account associated with the current session. The session value is initialized as follows:
>
>   If the user account has a nonzero `MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS` resource limit, the session [max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) value is set to that limit.
>
>   Otherwise, the session [max_user_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_user_connections) value is set to the global value.
>
>   Account resource limits are specified using the [`GRANT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html) statement. See [Section 6.3.4, “Setting Account Resource Limits”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-resources.html), and [Section 13.7.1.3, “`GRANT` Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html).

Comment: Ok that new to me, so can I manage them all in case of using VPS hosting that stated "All root access"?

Answer (score 1):

That's crazy. You can't have 1 database for each user. That's an over kill. (if you are not a hosting provider)

Anyway MySQL suggest to don't over come **4096 concurrent** requests per machine. I believe you will have many other problems than database if you will ever have 4096 concurrent requests.

Reference: [MySQL Best Pratices](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-administrator-best-practices.html)

Comment: Why not?  If one is running a hosting service in which one offers users access to their own MySQL database, one probably would have 1 database for each user.  I don't see why this is bad practise per-se, but of course the server/cluster will need sufficient resource to cope with anticipated load.

Comment: @eggyal: yea I didn't take in consideration the hosting provider. If he speaks from that point of view than I believe serverfault is the better place for this question.

Comment: I planned to have each user database to store just the personal data which quite often dynamic. Then the central database used to links relation between each user-database.

Comment: @Thanapom: In that case, I agree with yes123--you should [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data structure and keep all the data within a single database.